# Strange draw behavior of stacked area chart in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, stacked-area-chart

I have divided my stacked area chart into three main separated area and each area can have multiple another area inside. The all main areas should be in same yAxis line. For example the first area is whole alone but the second one contains two area which has the same xAxis interval but has different yAxis interval. The third should has three area inside where they have same xAxis interval but should have different yAxis area. For now I have just defined one area for the third one, but after draw the third area looks really strange.
I would like mention that I have set autorange of false for yAxis.

If anyone can explain me the strange behavior of the stacked area chart in JavaFX I would really appreciate.
The strange behavior can be seen on the picture below. Also provide example code how I define my series.

[image: picture of strange draw behavior of stacked area chart graph]

Using Java 1.8.0_212

```
 XYChart.Series<Double, Double> testSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
 XYChart.Series<Double, Double> testSeries2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
 XYChart.Series<Double, Double> testSeries3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
 XYChart.Series<Double, Double> testSeries4 = new XYChart.Series<>();

 testSeries.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
 testSeries2.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
 testSeries3.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
 testSeries4.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

 testSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(0.00, 99.99));
 testSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(479.99, 99.99));

 testSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(480.00, 49.99));
 testSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(959.99, 49.99));

 testSeries3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(480.00, 99.99));
 testSeries3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(959.99, 99.99));

 testSeries4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(960.00, 49.99));
 testSeries4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(1439.99, 49.99));

 StackedAreaChart<Double, Double> chart = new StackedAreaChart<Double, Double>();
 chart.getData().addAll(testSeries, testSeries2, testSeries3, testSeries4);`
```

Comment: is there a reason why you add data to `testSeries4` but not add `testSeries4` to the chart?

Comment: Sorry my false. The mistake is repaired.